Is it possible to clear buff/cache memory in k8s?
I have a pod which has memory leak problems. As we can see in the picture, there are a lot of buff/cach memory.

We used to use docker swarm as the cluster orchestration and we can directly access to the cluster node. And we write a crontab on the cluster node to clear the buff/cache every day in the morning.
15 00 * * * /usr/sbin/sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3 >> /tmp/clean_cache.log 2>&1

However, we can't access to the cluster node directly in k8s, can we clear the buff/cache still?

Why don't you add requests and limits to the pod itself? It may be a more logical solution.

Or instrument the container to find the memory leak

@OmidEstaji You mean it!! I should make my limits.memory higher.

Those buffers are managed by the kernel and generally make disk I/O faster.  That number being high isn't necessarily a sign of a problem, and I wouldn't expect to ever need to run that sysctl command.  Have you profiled your application to see how it's using memory?  (That PNG file is significantly larger than the plain-text free output, which could cost time and space, and it suggests to me the machine has about 4x as much memory as it needs.)

@DavidMaze good answer!! Here we use python language and in our code we we import some third-party package which written by C++. It is very hard to find out where exactly the memory is leaked. Secondly, by using the crontab to clear the buffer/cache, we find out that some of our service which will be killed in the past no longer have such issues. This is the reason why we think clear the cache might help.

It is more logical to limit resources in pod (workload) level. For this purpose you can specify a memory request and a memory limit for the pod, an example manifest:
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: memory-demo
  namespace: mem-example
spec:
  containers:
  - name: memory-demo-ctr
    image: polinux/stress
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "100Mi"
      limits:
        memory: "200Mi"
    command: ["stress"]
    args: ["--vm", "1", "--vm-bytes", "150M", "--vm-hang", "1"]

More info here: Link
